# Можно ли переименовать файл перед отправкой на сервер?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вопрос заключается в следующем при помощи тега `<input type="file">` мы выбираем файл, и после нажатия кнопки мы его отправляем на сервер, так вот перед тем как отправить его на сервер хотелось бы ему дать новое имя и уже с новым именем отправить его на сервер.

```
function onChangeFile(e) {
    var eventData = e.dataTransfer || e.target;
    var files = eventData.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
        file[i].name = 'new-name-' + i + '.txt'; // расширение не важно...
    }
    //... тут дальше код обработки и отправки
}
```

Comment: Переименовать или сделать копию с новым импнем. И уже потом отправить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить через [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

У которого есть метод [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), который может принимать два или три параметра. В случае трех параметров будет выглядеть так:
`formData.append(name, value, filename);`, где 
как третий параметр то, что и нужно

> filename - Имя файла которое будет отправлено серверу
>   (USVString), когда Blob или File прошел проверку как второй параметр.
>   Стандартное имя файла для Blob объектов это "blob".

Минимальный пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myFile", document.getElementById("file").files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "index.php");
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="GO" />
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

В итоге на сервер полетит следующее:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

То есть картинка с именем `test.gpg`

Убедиться, что это правда - можно написав в `php` банальный `print_r($_FILES)` и получим:

```
Array
(
    [myFile] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => W:\userdata\temp\php7731.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 875248
        )
)
```

Comment: IE 10+?..........