# Как передать файл или содержимое файла на сервер

Tags: javascript

Рылся в гугле, и никак не мог найти передачу самого файла посредством `<input type="file">`
Были передачи имени, размера. Как добраться до данных выбранного файла? Чтобы если не передавать сам файл, то хотя бы передать его содержимое. Как добраться до данных в этом `input`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: http://www.php.su/phphttp/?uploads

Comment: Это я находил. У меня `$_FILES` (в `$GLOBALS` даже нет намека на передаваемые мной данные) в принимающем скрипте пустой. Мне нужно, только средствами ДжаваСкрипта отправить содержимое файла.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381936/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-file) обсуждался способ отправки файлов средствами ДжаваСкрипт

Answer (score 6):

Ссылаясь на самого себя https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512748/191482,
можно воспользоваться [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) для этих нужд

`FormData` - создает новые объект FormData, если проще - HTML-форму.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myFile", document.getElementById("file").files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "index.php");
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="GO" />
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

При клике на кнопку с id `btn` отправится запрос на сервер и передаст файл из инпута с идентификатором `file`

Также можно отправлять много файлов. Для этого требуется лишь в цикле добавить все файлы в форму и потом отправить через аякс.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file");
var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, file;
for (; i < len; i++) {
    file = filedata.files[i];
    formdata.append("file", file);
}
```

Конечно можно еще проще. Просто в конструктор `FromData` передать саму форму и запулить.
Пример через `jquery`

```js
$("form#data").submit(function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
 
  // складируем форму в ......форму))
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'mySuperPuperURL.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      alert(returndata);
    }
  });
 
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="data">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" readonly="readonly">
  User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br />
  Profile Image: <input name="profileImg[]" type="file" /><br />
  Display Image: <input name="displayImg[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let file = document.getElementById('inpute-type-file-id').files[0];
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('stringKeyToGetValue', file);

$.ajax({
   url: 'your/url/address/here.html',
   method: 'post',
   data: formData,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: (response) => {
   //...
   },
   error: (response) => {
   ...
   }
})
```