# Загрузка изображений ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Делаю некий список, у каждого эл-та списка рядом есть блок, по клику на который должно открываться окно выбора файла с ПК и далее отправлялся по ajax. Нашёл такой пример, но не могу добиться, чтобы передавался id элемента.
 Не нашёл решение в интернете и сам не могу додумать.

[Пример нашёл здесь](http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/108-zagruzchik_izobrazhenij_na_server.html)

Comment: там используется плагин, не факт что можно передать с его помощью id с веб-страницы, пример закачки без плагинов тут https://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-zagruzka-fajlov.html в .ajax({data: ...}} передавайте все что хотите

Comment: Можно воспользоваться FormData (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).... где можно передать id как имя файла...... например name_1, name_2 и т.д....... как это сделать написано вот тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516021/191482  ....

Comment: напишите пожалуйста Ваш код, чтобы можно было увидеть что у Вас получилось и в каком месте у Вас проблема. Что касается передачи данных(id и пр.) смотрите коммент @АлексейШиманский выше.