# в POST переменную не передается файл php

Tags: php, ajax, form

Разметка:

```
<form id="load-img" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <ul data-tab="4" class="__tab">
       <li>
            <label class="fileupload1">
                <input id="img-load" type="file" name="img" size="20">
            </label>
       </li>
       <li>
             <input class="load-img-sub" type="submit" name="download">
       </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

js:

```
$("#load-img").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var img = $("#img-load").val();
    $.post("<?=base_url()?>loadimg.php",{img:img},function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

код php:

```
if ($_POST)  {
$name = $_POST['img']['name'];
$tmp = $_POST['img']['tmp_name'];
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/".$_POST["img"]["name"];

if ($_POST["img"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
{
    echo (">3mb");
    exit;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)){
    print("Done! File saved...");
} else {
    die("Error on uploading! tmpName=" . $tmp . ' . Name=' . $name .
        '. path=' . $path );
}
} else {
    print_r ('no_post');
}
```

`console.log` выводит :`Error on uploading! tmpName=C . Name=C. path=Z:/home/test1.ru/subdomain/img/C`. Какая еще `C`?? Весь день с этой проблемой просидел

Comment: А вы в курсе, что файлы и их данные прилетают в **[$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php)**, а не `$_POST` ?

Comment: дополнил сообщение. Первые пол дня пинал $_FILES, но потом случайно увидел POST для файлов. Заменил, ответ от сервера стал на одну букву более информативный. Дополнил вопрос выше

Comment: ну и `$("#img-load").val();` файл не передаст

Comment: @Igor `var img = $("#load-img").serialize();
        $.post("<?=base_url()?>loadimg.php",{img:img},function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });` такой код не меняет ничего

Comment: @Igor как иначе передать файл?

Comment: @Igor ну зачем сразу на enSO? )) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516021/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пардон, удаляю

Comment: @Igor спасибо вам. Сложно передать благодарность после такой помощи. На php заставила нужда писать, немного стыдно за незнание подобного. Сейчас исправлю вопрос так, чтобы там был правильный ответ

Comment: @Nikolay Не за что, главное, что Вы разобрались и стали опытнее. На заметку: записи `this` и `$(this)[0]` - эквивалентны. Успехов в программировании!

Comment: @Nikolay так тут не делается. Если у вас есть решение — опишите его в ответе. P.S. Вопрос ваш я откатил к первоначальной версии

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понял, сейчас

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в js при отправке формы.
Вот код js:

```
$("#load-img").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/uploadst",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
            console.log(returndata);
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
if($_FILES)  {
    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/static/img/product/".$_FILES["img"]["name"];

    if($_FILES["img"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
    {
        echo (">3mb");
        exit;
    }
    if ( ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ) {

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)){
            print("Done! File saved...");
        } else {
            die("Error on uploading! tmpName=" . $tmp . ' . Name=' . $name .
                '. path=' . $path );
        }
    }
} else {
    print_r ($_FILES["img"]["type"]. 'no_post');
}
```