# Передача изображения в base64 на сервер. Чем заменить?

Tags: php, javascript, изображения, base64

У меня есть код JS. При загрузке пользователем изображений, он их уменьшает, впихивает в canvas и выводит миниатюру. А оригинальное изображение кодирует в base64, засовывает в невидимый input и передаёт на сервер. Но если файл большой, то длина его получается огромная, а если ещё и не один файл, то браузер вообще виснет. Чем можно заменить эту конструкцию?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="file" multiple="" id="photo">
</div>
<div>
    <ul id="preview-photo">
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    var previewWidth = 150, // ширина превью
        previewHeight = 150, // высота превью
        maxFileSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024, // (байт) Максимальный размер файла (2мб)
        selectedFiles = {},// объект, в котором будут храниться выбранные файлы
        queue = [],
        image = new Image(),
        imgLoadHandler,
        isProcessing = false,
        errorMsg, // сообщение об ошибке при валидации файла
        previewPhotoContainer = document.querySelector('#preview-photo'); // контейнер, в котором будут отображаться превью

        // Когда пользователь выбрал файлы, обрабатываем их
        $('input[type=file][id=photo]').on('change', function() {
            var newFiles = $(this)[0].files; // массив с выбранными файлами

            for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {

                var file = newFiles[i];

                // В качестве "ключей" в объекте selectedFiles используем названия файлов
                // чтобы пользователь не мог добавлять один и тот же файл
                // Если файл с текущим названием уже существует в массиве, переходим к следующему файлу
                if (selectedFiles[file.name] != undefined) continue;

                // Валидация файлов (проверяем формат и размер)
                if ( errorMsg = validateFile(file) ) {
                    alert(errorMsg);
                    return;
                }

                // Добавляем файл в объект selectedFiles
                selectedFiles[file.name] = file;
                queue.push(file);

            }

            $(this).val('');
            processQueue(); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюр
        });

        // Валидация выбранного файла (формат, размер)
        var validateFile = function(file)
        {
            if ( !file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/) ) {
                return 'Фотография должна быть в формате jpg, png или gif';
        }

        if ( file.size > maxFileSize ) {
            return 'Размер фотографии не должен превышать 2 Мб';
        }
    };

    var listen = function(element, event, fn) {
        return element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    };

    // Создание миниатюры
    var processQueue = function()
    {
        // Миниатюры будут создаваться поочередно
        // чтобы в один момент времени не происходило создание нескольких миниатюр
        // проверяем запущен ли процесс
    if (isProcessing) { return; }

    // Если файлы в очереди закончились, завершаем процесс
    if (queue.length == 0) {
        isProcessing = false;
        return;
    }

    isProcessing = true;

    var file = queue.pop(); // Берем один файл из очереди

    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var spanDel = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    span.setAttribute('class', 'img');
    spanDel.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
    spanDel.innerHTML = '<img src="/public/images/deletes.svg">';

    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(spanDel);
    li.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);                                                                              
    image.removeEventListener('load', imgLoadHandler, false);

    // создаем миниатюру
    imgLoadHandler = function() {
        ratio = realW/realH;
        previewHeight = 100;
        previewWidth = 100 * ratio;

        canvas.setAttribute('width', previewWidth); //ширина области отображения превью
        canvas.setAttribute('height', previewHeight); //высота области отображения превью
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        span.appendChild(canvas);
        isProcessing = false;
        setTimeout(processQueue, 200); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюры для следующего изображения
    };

    // Выводим миниатюру в контейнере previewPhotoContainer                                     
    previewPhotoContainer.appendChild(li);
    listen(image, 'load', imgLoadHandler);
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Сохраняем содержимое оригинального файла в base64 в отдельном поле формы
    // чтобы при отправке формы файл был передан на сервер
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    fr.onload = (function (file){
        return function (e) {
        realW = image.width;
        realH = image.height;
        $('#preview-photo').append(
            '<input type="hidden" name="photos[]" value="' + e.target.result + '" data-id="' + file.name+ '">'
        );
    }
}) (file);
};

// Удаление фотографии
 $(document).on('click', '#preview-photo li span.delete', function() {
      var fileId = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');

     if (selectedFiles[fileId] != undefined) delete selectedFiles[fileId]; 
 // Удаляем файл из объекта selectedFiles                                                  
   $(this).parents('li').remove(); // Удаляем превью
   $('input[name^=photo][data-id="' + fileId + '"]').remove(); // Удаляем поле с содержимым файла
});

 </script>
```

Comment: нормальной отправкой файла на сервер? Вроде сейчас нет никаких проблем передачи файлов на сервер асинхронно и вывод миниатюр.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев а можете пожалуйста подсказать, как это сделать? Я с ассинхнронностью не знаком :(

Comment: Можно так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648374/17974

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо большое