# Отправка файла через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Подскажите, почему файл не получается передать на сервер?

```
   <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" requered><br>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" requered><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
                        <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Комментарий" name="text-comments"></textarea>
                        <input type="file" name="file"><br>
                        <input id="form-action" type="button" class="send" value="Купить в один клик"><br>
                    </div>
                </form>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click","#form-action", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($("input[name='fio']").val()!="" && $("textarea").val()!=""){

            var data = $("form").serialize();
            $.post("/ajax/handler.php",{data},function(data,status){
                console.log(data);
                $(".block_error").html("<div class='col-md-offset-1 text-left'><span style='color:#f29400'>Ваше сообщение отправленно.</span></div>");
                //location.reload();
            }); 
        }
        else {
            $(".block_error").html("<div class='col-md-offset-1 text-left'><span style='color:red'>Заполните обязательные поля</span></div>");
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: могу предложить взглянуть на [этот вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516002)  и попробовать воспользоваться FormData для этих нужд  .... плюс вдогонку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512742

Answer (score 2):

Написал вот такой костыльный вариант, буду рад если кто нибудь его оптимизирует

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click","#form-action", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        file = new FormData();
        file.append( 'file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0] );

        var data = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: "/ajax/handler.php.php",
            data:  file, 
        })
        .done(function( file ) {
            console.log(file)
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/handler.php.php",
            data:  {data}, 
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: Конструктор `FormData` позволяет принять уже поля с формы.... то есть... если у формы будет к примеру `name="myform"`, то можно написать `var formData = new FormData(document.forms.myform);` либо `var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);` ......... а далее просто добавить файл `formData .append( 'file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0] );` и уже просто тупо отправить в одном запросе `data:  formData`

Comment: то есть в итоге что-то типа такого http://pastebin.com/MdTXgeGC  и никаких костылей

Answer (score -4):

Формы с файлами нельзя сабмитить аяксово. Кажется, это связано с безопасностью. В любом случае - нельзя, факт. Но решения есть.

Часть решений перед аяксовой отправкой формы смотрит, есть ли в ней файлинпуты, и есть ли в файлинпутах файлы. И, если есть - скрипт сабмитит форму неаяксово.

Пример такого решения: [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)

Другая часть решений при сабмите формы создает невидимый iframe с ней же и сабмитит ее неаяксовым методом. Так как iframe невидим - то со стороны пользователя форма сабмитится "как будто" аяксово. Скрипт тем временем следит за iframe, и когда в него приходит ответ от сервера - скрипт вставляет содержимое iframe в страницу, а сам iframe удаляет.

Пример такого решения: [jquery-iframe-transport](https://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/)

> Еще одним решением является аяксовая отправка файлов мимо формы. Например [blueimp/jQuery-file-upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) делает так. В этом случае в форме не должно быть инпутов для выбора файлов, сами файлы будут закачиваться независимо от формы.

Comment: через аякс можно передавать файлы, но нельзя сабмитить формы с файлами

Comment: @ChromeChrome, странно, что вы удалили свой комментарий, мое уточнение потеряло смысл. Вы говорили, что я ошибаюсь, и нельзя передавать файлы через аякс. Я уточнил, что можно, но нельзя аяксово сабмитить формы с файлами. И дополнил ответ решением по передаче файлов через аякс независимо от формы.